# Form 15G: Exemption on TDS if total income is > 2.5L but taxable income is < 2.5L

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-exemption

I need one clarification. If one's total income is greater than 2.5 Lakhs per annum, but still having taxable income less than 2.5L (due to 80C etc.), can they submit Form 15G to get exemption on TDS from dividends, interest income etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if taxable income is less than 2.5 Lac, you can submit Form 15G and avoid TDS.